# Normalizr with nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, redux, normalizr

I have a nested array of objects like this:

```
var matchs = [
    {
      id: 10689,
      sport: 'Tennis',
      players: [
        {
        id: 22,
        name:'Rafa Nadal',
        country: 'Spain',
        odds: [
           {id: 1, bookie_1: 1.60},
           {id: 2, bookie_2: 1.61},
           {id: 3, bookie_3: 1.62},
           ]
        },
        {
        id: 23,
        name:'Roger Federer',
        country: 'Spain',
        odds: [
           {id: 4, bookie_1: 2.60},
           {id: 5, bookie_2: 2.61},
           {id: 6, bookie_3: 2.62},
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 12389,
      sport: 'Tennis',
      players: [
        {
        id: 45,
        name:'Fernando Verdasco',
        country: 'Spain',
        odds: [
           {id: 7, bookie_1: 2.60},
           {id: 8, bookie_2: 2.61},
           {id: 9, bookie_3: 2.62},
          ]
        },
        {
        id: 65,
        name:'Andy Murray',
        country: 'Spain',
        odds: [
           {id: 10, bookie_1: 1.60},
           {id: 11, bookie_2: 1.61},
           {id: 12, bookie_3: 1.62},
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I want to use normalizr to simplify array and use with redux. I have read the Normalizr documentation but it has few examples and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I have tried the following code without success. The result I get is an array with undefined.

```
  import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';   

  const match = new schema.Entity('matchs');
  const player = new schema.Entity('players');
  const odd = new schema.Entity('odds');

  match.define({
    player: [player],
    odd: [odd]
  });      

  console.log(normalize(matchs, [match]));
```

I need something like this:

```
{
  result: "123",
  entities: {
    "matchs": { 
      "123": { 
        id: "123",            
        players: [ "1","2" ],
        odds: [ "1", "2" ]
      }
    },
    "players": {
      "1": { "id": "1", "name": "Rafa Nadal" },
      "2": { "id": "2", "name": "Andy Murray" }
    },
    "odds": {
      "1": { id: "1", "bookie_1": "1.20" }
      "2": { id: "2", "bookie_2": "1.21" }
      "3": { id: "3", "bookie_3": "1.22" }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to look final array ?

Comment: I update code with result I want

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a straight solution using only normalizr, so my only choice is to pre-format the data before passing to the normalizer.

```
const preformattedData = data.map(sport => {
  const oddArrays = sport.players.map(player => player.odds || []);
  return {
    ...sport,
    odds: [].concat.apply([], oddArrays)
  }
})

const odd = new schema.Entity('odds')
const player = new schema.Entity('players',
  {
    odds: [ odd ]
  }
)
const sport = new schema.Entity('sports',
  {
    players: [ player ],
    odds: [odd]
  }
)

const normalizedData = normalize(preformattedData, [ sport ]);
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/20onxowzwn

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
const odd = new schema.Entity('odds');
const player = new schema.Entity('players' , { odds: [ odd]});

const match = new schema.Entity('matchs', {players: [player]});
```

but the result will be different because your json it is structured like this, I mean, the odds key is child of players, not of matches, therefore the result will be this way.

Just take a look at the console

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with latest version of normalizr

```
const odds = new schema.Entity("odds");
const players = new schema.Entity("players", {
  odds: [odds]
});
const matches = new schema.Entity("matches", { players: [players] });
const normalizedData = normalize(data, [matches]);
```

It would group data in your question as

```
{
 "entities": {
    "odds": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "bookie_1": 1.6
        }
    },
    "players": {
        "22": {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "Rafa Nadal",
            "country": "Spain",
            "odds": [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ]
        }
    },
    "matches": {
        "10689": {
            "id": 10689,
            "sport": "Tennis",
            "players": [
                22,
                23
            ]
        }
    }
},
"result": [
    10689
]
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your desired result by tweaking the process and merge strategies. I don't have time to do the leg work for you, but I explain the approach in detail here:

https://medium.com/@JustinTRoss/normalizing-data-into-relational-redux-state-with-normalizr-47e7020dd3c1